# How to create continuously changing variables in Python

Tags: python

In pseudocode, you can create variables such as 'variable(x)', having x as a forever changing number therefore creating multiple different variables. For example, if:

```
x = 0
variable(x) = 4
x = 1
variable(x) = 7
```

then printing 'variable(0)' would give you the result '4' and printing 'variable(1)' would output '7'. My question is: is this possible to do in Python?

Comment: Do you want something like a switch-case? If So, you can use a dict. `def variable(x): return {0:4,1:7}[x]`?

Comment: do you want an array that is called `variable`? then you could call `variable[0]` to get a value

Comment: do you maybe want to write a *function* that maps `x` to different values??

Comment: The psedocode you're showing **doesn't** define define `variable` as a variable, but as a *function* of `x`.

Comment: Am I right to presume Python is your first programming language? You should really be reading a Python tutorial.

Comment: I would but I'm not sure what subtopic this question would come under and a tutorial may not even include this. Besides, I have the answer now :)

Comment: Don't worry about subtopics. Please read [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) in its entirety, following along and running the examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use exactly that syntax in Python, but you can come close using a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict).

```
variable = {}
x = 0
variable[x] = 4
x = 1
variable[x] = 7
print(variable[0])
print(variable[1])
```

If the domain of your variable is non-negative integers, and you know the largest integer *a priori*, then you could use a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange):

```
variable = [None]*2
x = 0
variable[x] = 4
x = 1
variable[x] = 7
print(variable[0])
print(variable[1])
```

Comment: Thank you, Rob. This is very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

The nearest could be a list:

```
x = []
x.append(4)
x.append(7)

print(x[0])
4
print(x[1])
7
```

And if you don't want to use a count as identifier you can use Rob's answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use dictionary

```
    variable = {} 
    variable['0'] = 4
    variable['1'] = 7

    x=1
    print varibale[x]
```

will print 7

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as your pseudocode doesn't declare a *variable*, but a *function*, it's pretty easy to build something like this:

```
def my_function(x):
    return 3*x + 4
```

Then you can

```
print my_function(0)
4
print my_function(1)
7
```

Of course, you can do pretty much everything in that function; the mathematical linear mapping I used was just an example. You could be reading a whole file, looking for `x` in it and returning e.g. the line number, you could be tracking satellite positions and return the current position of satellite Nr. `x`... This is python, a fully-fledged programming language that supports functions, like pretty much every non-declarative programming language I can think of.